# Probability that sum of 3 iid uniform random numbers exceeds 1

Tags: probability

The solution for two uniformly iid variables can be found here:

[Choosing two random numbers in $(0,1)$ what is the probability that sum of them is more than $1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285362/choosing-two-random-numbers-in-0-1-what-is-the-probability-that-sum-of-them)

However I have generalising to the case where there are three variables:

I try to generalize Rahul's answer:

For the general case, if $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are three independent, identically distributed variables with probability distribution function $f$ supported in $[0,1]$, then the probability that their sum exceeds $1$ is
$$\begin{align}
P[X+Y+Z\ge1]=\iint\limits_{\substack{0\le x\le1\\0\le y\le1\\0\le z\le1\\{x+y+z\ge1}}} f(x)f(y)f(z)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz=\int_0^1f(x)\left(\int_{1-x}^1f(y)\left(\int_{1-x-y}^1f(z)\,\mathrm dz\right)\,\mathrm dy\right)\,\mathrm dx\\=\int_0^1f(x)\int_{1-x}^1f(y)\big(1-F(1-x-y)dy\big)\,\mathrm dx,
\end{align}$$
where $F(t)=\int_0^tf(u)\,\mathrm du$ is the cumulative distribution function of the random variables.

Is this correct so far?

How can I use this expression to calculate the probability that X+Y+Z>1?

Comment: Easier to compute the probability that they add up to less than $1$, because that's the volume of a relatively simple region, a pyramid with corners $(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$.

Comment: The probability that $n$ such numbers adds up to less than $1$ is $\frac{1}{n!}$.

Comment: Here's a general argument for $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n\leq 1$ has probability $1/n!$. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/315300/7933

Comment: Hi Thomas can you show me how you get to the 1/n! expression?

Comment: Take a cube of side $1$, and let $P$ be a vertex. Let $A,B,C$ be the adjoining vertices, and draw the plane through these. This cuts off a tetrahedral chunk from the cube. By geometry this chunk has volume $\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: My basic argument is that if you pick a sequence of $n$ random numbers, the probability that they come out sorted is "obviously" $1/n!$, and then I prove that the set $\{\sum x_i\leq 1\}$ is the image of the "sorted" set under a linear transformation that preserves volumes. There's probably a more direct geometric approach, but I like the "obvious" part about sorting probabilities.

Comment: The title says that you're interested in uniformly distributed numbers, but the body doesn't -- please bing them into agreement.